# Get unique record from database and have all comma separated ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have table and want to find duplicate names records with comma separated ids

```
table users
Id     name
1      xyz
2      abc
3      def
4      xyz
5      sss
6      def
```

I want Ids of users unique record with comma separated ids, in my example I want 1,4 for user 'xyz' and 3,6 for user 'def'

I have tried with unique query but it return only with last or first id

Looking for help in either mysql query or laravel eloquent.

Comment: `SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM users GROUP BY name`

Comment: @Akina You probably want an `ORDER BY id` clause inside `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP tells nothing about the IDs list to be sorted.

Comment: @Akina Your query works!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 3):

```php
// get the ids of users with the name `xyz` and join them together
User::where('name', 'xyz')->pluck('id')->join(',')
```

If you want to do it for all users:

```php
$data = [];
User::pluck('name')->each(function ($user) {
    $data[] = [
        'name' => $user;
        'matches' => User::where('name', $user)->pluck('id')->join(',')
    ];
});
```

You'll then have an array like:

```
[['name' => 'xyz', 'matches' => '1,4'], [['name' => 'abc', 'matches' => '2'], [...]]
```

Comment: I do not need for single name it should be query for all names from table

Comment: I added an example of looping through this

Comment: I have used select(DB::raw('group_concat(id) as ids') and then groupBy('name')

Comment: User::select(DB::raw('group_concat(id) as ids'), 'name')->groupBy('name')->get()->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$values = [];
$user = User::where('name', 'xyz');
$users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('name',$user->name)->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
     foreach(explode(',', $users ->id) as $value) {
     $values[] = trim($value);
  }
}
$values = array_unique($values);
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing it, as you're getting the entire user table from the database and then processing it in php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL using:

```
select name, group_concat(id) as id
from t
group by name
```

If you only want names with more than one id, then add:

```
having count(*) > 1
```